# where is com.intellij.rt.junit.junitstarter

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

i use intellij with junit to run tests (new), when i debug my test code for practice, one of the very first lines of code that seems to run is some method called main from package called com.intellij.rt.junit. I've tried clicking on it as well as searching for it open that package or class to see what's inside but i can't find it all. anyone know what it is or where i could find it in intellij and why i can't just access it from the debugger like every other class? i have junit 5.8 installed in maven.

[image: screenshot of debug screen]

Comment: Could you please share sample project example?

Comment: @y.bedrov I attached a screenshot if it helps, that's what my debug screen shows when i run tests using junit, it's the same when i use testng except, it says com.intelli.rt.testng

Comment: As far as I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side it would be great if you could provide sample project example.

Comment: @y.bedrov so i quickly made an example and uploaded it to github below. if u clone it and then open the java print class and put a breakpoint at line 9 then run it with debug, then in the debug screen it should show at the bottom, if it doesn't then that's all i got lol.

https://github.com/Coldplay23/example

Comment: Thanks! "JUnitStarter" is a part of bundled "JUnit" support plugin: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/8270253c66f00b11a1937524f4950e063403345d/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/rt/junit/JUnitStarter.java

Comment: @y.bedrov any ideas on why u can't access it in intellij?

Comment: It's not a part of a classpath. It's just a launcher. Just like OS level libraries used for execution won't be accessed during debug.

Comment: @y.bedrov when u say it's not part of the classpath, do u mean that same library u shared with me in that link above isn't anywhere in the libraries i'm using in that program i shared with u.

Comment: Exactly. It's a part of IDE, not a part of debugged application.

Comment: @y.bedrov good enough for me, thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y.bedrov's analysis is quite right.

`com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter` is part of IDE. In your case, the IDE is IntelliJ IDEA. You may find the source code in this local path:

> /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar

then import the jar package into your own project to read the source code conveniently.

[image]